# Building a Hardhat Project in an AWS EC2 Debian Box, Vyper Compiler Error

Tags: hardhat, vyper, aws, linux, debian

Everything is working, solidity contracts compile. But I want to use Vyper; I love vyper, because Vitalik Buterin made it and it has such beautiful simplicity.

For some reason I cannot get hardhats vyper compiler to work in my Debian box. I followed all instructions in HardHat documentation but I get this error after trying to compile with only helloWorld.vy in the contracts directory

```
>sudo npx hardhat compile

An unexpected error occurred:

Error: Command failed: /root/.cache/hardhat-nodejs/compilers-v2/vyper/linux/0.3.0 -f combined_json /workspace/ethereum/hardhatProject1/contracts/helloworld.vy
/bin/sh: 1: /root/.cache/hardhat-nodejs/compilers-v2/vyper/linux/0.3.0: Exec format error

    at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:422:12)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:517:28)
    at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1098:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (node:internal/child_process:450:11)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:517:28)
    at Pipe.<anonymous> (node:net:351:12) {
  code: 126,
  killed: false,
  signal: null,
  cmd: '/root/.cache/hardhat-nodejs/compilers-v2/vyper/linux/0.3.0 -f combined_json /workspace/ethereum/hardhatProject1/contracts/helloworld.vy'
```

GPT 4 is suggesting that the HH vyper compiler is not compatible with the Debian OS.